# How to replace matches pattern with html tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

**I have some html code following**

```
<span style="color:#c5c5c5;">
 This is sample text </span> with ^(upper) text 
 and some ^(trademark) ^(copyright) symbols !
```

Now i'm using javascript to replace all string start with ^( and end with )

**this is result i want**

```
<span style="color:#c5c5c5;">This is sample text </span> with <sup>upper</sup> text and some <sup>trademark</sup> <sup>copyright</sup> symbols !
```

I'm using function and regex, to replace all string that match a patterm

**Javascript Here !**

```
var pattern = /\^\(.*\)/;
```

But i don't know how to using while() to replace all i want  :-s

Comment: You should probably use non-greedy matching. Or even this: /\^\\([^)]*\\)/

Answer (score 0):

@Sniffer is on the right track. I believe what you're looking for is

```
sampleText.replace(/\^\((.*?)\)/g, "<sup>$1</sup>")
```

Or incorporating @MaxArt's suggestion,

```
sampleText.replace(/\^\(([^)]*)\)/g, "<sup>$1</sup>")
```